# Android App - Video/Audio Record

Tags: php, android, flash

I have to develop an app for android devices [I have no prior experience in development of android apps].

This app should be capable of recording a video / audio and communicate over rtmp with red5 streaming server. I already have video recorder and audio recorder in flash capable of recording in flv format and currently are used in a php website. Can I use these .swf and php files in android app? or I need to write a new one in java / action script 3? Is android capable of playing flv files, I meant to say will it be able to play if I pass flv file URL (to the flv player) in app. I am guessing it would be better if I directly access the device camera / microphone and record the flv.

Also, which language is recommended for my scenario, java or action script 3.0?

Any guidance / directions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use your existing .swf and .php code for this project, but you specifically have to publish your flash content to Adobe AIR in order to run it on an Android device.

You can do pretty much anything on a phone that you can do in a regular AIR app, though there are additional considerations (bandwidth, performance, etc.).

Which language you choose depends on your future plans for the app. If you already have most of the code written in AS3, it may be easier to just adapt it for mobile scenarios. Also, if you intend to eventually deploy to iPhone as well it will be easier to work with AS3 as you can just publish the same AIR app to both devices without rewriting it.

If you're concerned about performance and API access, and you have no interest in porting to iPhone, I suggest using Java.